# How to reload window after success case

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, api

I'm using ReactJS with Laravel API and I  don't know why the window won't reload, and I didn't get the success message. even the status is correct

this my frontend code :

```
 const addUnit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('unit_name', unit_name);
    formData.append('building_id', building_id);
    formData.append('floor_id', floor_id);
    formData.append('type_id', type_id);
    formData.append('user_id', user_id);
    formData.append('unit_status', unit_status);
    formData.append('unit_roomnumber', unit_roomnumber);
    formData.append('unit_added_date', unit_added_date);
    formData.append('unit_rent_per_month', unit_rent_per_month);
    formData.append('frais_percent', frais_percent);
    for (let i = 0; i < unit_pictures.length; i++) {
      formData.append('unit_pictures[]', unit_pictures[i])
    }
    axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}/api/addUnite`, formData).then(response => {
      if (response.data.status === 200) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
      else if (response.data.status == 400) {
        new Swal("warning", response.data.errors, "Warning");
      }
      })}
```

this is backend code :

```
 public function addUnite(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'unit_name' => 'required|max:191',
            'unit_status' => 'required',
            'unit_roomnumber' => 'required',
            'unit_added_date' => 'required',
            'unit_rent_per_month' =>'required' 


        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 422,
                'errors' => "All Fields Are required !",
            ]);


        }
        else {
            $exist = Unite::where('type_id', '=', Input::get('type_id'))
                ->where('unit_roomnumber', '=', Input::get('unit_roomnumber'))
                ->where('building_id', '=', Input::get('building_id'))
                ->exists();

            if ($exist) {
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 400,
                    'errors' => "This Unit already exist !",
                ]);
        
             
            }
        else {
            $unit = new Unite();
            $unit->unit_name = $request->input('unit_name');
            $unit->building_id = $request->input('building_id');
            $unit->unit_id = $request->input('unit_id');
            $unit->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
            $unit->frais_percent = $request->input('frais_percent');
            $unit->floor_id = $request->input('floor_id');
            $unit->type_id = $request->input('type_id');
            $unit->unit_status = $request->input('unit_status');
            $unit->unit_roomnumber = $request->input('unit_roomnumber');
            $unit->unit_added_date = $request->input('unit_added_date');
            $unit->unit_rent_per_month = $request->input('unit_rent_per_month');

            // $unit->unit_pictures = $request->file('unit_pictures'); 
            $allUploadApiReponse = array();

            foreach ($unit->unit_pictures = $request->file('unit_pictures') as $imagefile) {

                $uploadedFileUrl = cloudinary()->upload(
                    ($imagefile)->getRealPath(),
                    [
                        'folder' => 'Units',
                        'discard_original_filename' => true,

                    ]
                )->getSecurePath();
                array_push($allUploadApiReponse, $uploadedFileUrl);
            }
            // To check content
            print_r($allUploadApiReponse);
            $unit->unit_pictures = $allUploadApiReponse;
            if($unit->save()){
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Unit Added Successfully",
                'status' => 200,

            ]);}
        }
```

PS: the unit is added successfully but I didn't get the success message

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe issue from your [react-router](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter) when trying routing from browser.

Not sure but you can try:

```js
history.go(0);
```

or

```js
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Comment: no even the swal didn't showin

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this code:

```js
axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}/api/addUnite`, formData).then(response => {
  if (response.data.status === 200) {
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'success',
      title: 'Unit Added Successfully',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500
    });
    setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(), 1500);
  } else if (response.data.status == 400) {
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'warning',
      title: 'Warning',
      text: response.data.errors
    });
  }
});
```